# Iteration over vector doesn't invoke functions

Tags: c++, vector

It seems that iteration over feed vector doesn't invoke draw functions. I added a few breakpoints inside and none of them was triggered.

Data is a vector of strings delivered by other part of my program and it works correctly (output file is fine).

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<NewsRenderer>> feed;

std::unique_ptr<NewsRenderer> ptr=std::make_unique<NewsRenderer>(NewsRenderer(sf::Vector2i(300, 100), "test-title", "test-url"));
feed.push_back(std::move(ptr));

myfile.close();

while (window.isOpen())
{
    window.clear(sf::Color::White);
    for (int i = 0; i < feed.size(); i++)
    {
        feed[i]->draw(0, 100 * i);
    }

    window.display();
}
```

There is NewsRenderer.h

```
#include "News.h"

#include <iostream>
class NewsRenderer
{
public:
    NewsRenderer(std::string title, std::string url, std::string decription="");
    void draw(int x, int y);
    ~NewsRenderer();
private:
    News* newsData;
};
```

And NewsRenderer.cpp

```
NewsRenderer::NewsRenderer(std::string title, std::string url, std::string decription)
{
    newsData = new News{ title, url, decription };
}

void NewsRenderer::draw(int x, int y)
{
    draw(title, x, y); //magic, but I didn't want to use any libraries in this example
}

NewsRenderer::~NewsRenderer()
{
}
```

So my questions are: what's going on? And how can I fix it?

PS. I tried to keep it simple, so if I skipped any important detail let me know and I'll deliver.

Comment: If you step through the code line by line in a debugger, does it seem to work as it should?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes. It works until it get to 'feed[i]->draw'. Then it just skip this line without jumping into draw function.

Comment: @PasserBy Oh... What's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: How many elements are in `feed`, and what happens when you try constructing it "by hand" with a single element with known contents? I'm willing to bet this code could be much simpler and still produce the error.

Comment: @Beta Vector size is currently 18, but when I followed your suggestion and pushed only one test-object nothing changed.

Comment: Just for kicks and grins, remove the `NewsRenderer(...)` wrapper around your creation of your unique pointer. I.e., it should read as: `std::make_unique<NewsRenderer>(sf::Vector2i(300, 100), element.attribute("title").as_string(), element.attribute("href").as_string());` And are you *really* leaking that `News` dynamic member (i.e., is your destructor *really* empty)?

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry, but I'm not sure if I got your idea. I removed NewsRenderer and it looks:
`feed.push_back(std::make_unique<NewsRenderer>(NewsRenderer(sf::Vector2i(300, 100), element.attribute("title").as_string(), element.attribute("href").as_string())));`
It doesn't help. And News is a struct so it doesn't have destructor or anything.

Comment: Yeah, you didn't get it. look at what I put in my prior comment. The construction of your unique pointer should not require `NewsRenderer(...)` wrapping the constructor arguments. `std::make_unique` supports variadic arguments which are forwarded to the constructor. You should use that (not saying its your problem, but you should none-the-less) And you still didn't answer my question. Is your destructor *really* empty? Why is `newsData` even dynamic? I see no reason it can't be a concrete member, constructed on the member initialization list that is suspiciously being avoided for some reason.

Comment: No reproducible example, no clear question. Care to edit?

Comment: @WhozCraig newsData is dynamic because I predict second option of setting data - just sending whole News struct initialized. I thought it will be helpful when I will be preparing more different kinds of renderers.

And now it's gonna be weird:`feed.push_back(std::make_unique<NewsRenderer>(sf::Vector2i(300, 100), element.attribute("title").as_string(), element.attribute("href").as_string()));` works perfectly. I have no idea why, but thanks.

Comment: @aerkenemesis I hope it's clear now.

Comment: My *guess* (all I can do, but that method of construction you were using looked suspicious) is that you have a [rule-of-three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation that rears in your code. Some debugging, and in particular, some *breakpoints* in your destructor (which I still suspect is *not* empty and thus not what you're showing here), would probably rear that out. Personally, I'd put `NewsRenderer(const NewsRenderer&)=delete;` in your class decl and find all the places that break. That class isn't copy-safe, so anyplace that breaks is bad code anyway.

Comment: @frogi16 please provide a reproducible example without external dependencies.

Comment: @WhozCraig I just copied and pasted my whole class so yes, destructor is really empty.

Comment: Then you still have a memory leak (`newsData`). Regardless, that class isn't copy-safe, so either copying shouldn't be allowed or it should be made safe. read the link I posted earlier about rule-of-three/five/zero. And good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct News {
    const std::string title;
    const std::string url;
    const std::string description;
};

struct NewsRenderer {
    NewsRenderer(std::string title, std::string url, std::string description="")
    : data(new News{title, url, description})
    { }

    ~NewsRenderer()
    { delete data; }

    void draw() const
    { std::cout << data->title << " - " << data->url << " - " << data->description << '\n'; }

    const News* data;
};

void foo() {
    std::cout << "foo()\n";
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<NewsRenderer>> feed{};

    auto p = std::make_unique<NewsRenderer>("title", "url", "description");
    //                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <= forwards arguments to NewsRenderers constructor
    feed.push_back( std::move(p) );
    for(auto& nr : feed) nr->draw();
}

void bar() {
    std::cout << "bar()\n";
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<NewsRenderer>> feed{};

    auto p = std::make_unique<NewsRenderer>(NewsRenderer{"title", "url", "description"});
    //                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <= tries to invoke copy constructor, not safe
    feed.push_back( std::move(p) );
    for(auto& nr : feed) nr->draw();
}

int main() {
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```